# multi-nested css flex does not flex properly

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

I'm doing a mockup using html and SCSS (or is it SASS?). The goal is to have page > container > [header + article container] where the articles are displayed in a grid.

I could have just tossed out a div-nade and just let the shrapnel of div#id land where it may, but instead I decided to use css flex and I am having problems. I know and understand the properties and their parameters, I just can't seem to get them together right.

How do I make this so that there's a limited number of items per row and and then it wraps to the next row?

Here's my pen: http://codepen.io/monsto/pen/ekazm

Here's the html:

```
<body>  Body FLEX
  <div class="main">    .main
    <header class="header">      .header      <nav>        Nav      </nav>    </header>
    <section class="pack">      section
      <article class="item text">        article
        <div class="item-content">
          <header class="entrytitle">a guy walks into a bar</header>
          <p></p>          <p></p>          <p></p>          <p></p>
        </div>
      </article>  <!-- copy <article> however many times for samples -->
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

And the SASS (or is it SCSS?). The commented stuff was basically to troubleshoot.

```
$bg: #eec;
$bord: #aaa;

@mixin colorize {
  $bg: darken($bg,8%);
  background-color: $bg;
  $bord: darken($bord,10%);
  border-color: $bord;
}

@mixin flex-spec
{
  display: flex;
  //flex: 1;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

* {box-sizing: border-box;}

html {  z-index: -10;
}

/*body {
  border:none; 
  background-color: #444;
  overflow: auto;
}*/

body * {
  // affects all children of body
  font: bold 16px arial;
  border-radius: 8px;
  // flex: 1;
  border: 5px solid $bord;
  @include colorize;
  //margin: 4px; padding: 0px;
}

div.main {
  @include colorize;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;

  header.header {
    @include colorize;
    nav {
      @include colorize;
    }
  }

  section {
    @include colorize;
    padding: 2px;
    article {
      @include colorize;
      * {border: none; border-radius: 1px;}
      div.item-content {
        @include colorize;
        border: 1px solid white;
        //margin: 0;
        header {//margin: 0;
          @include colorize;
        }
        p {height: 10px; margin: 0 0 10px;}
      }
      &.embiggen {
        align-items: stretch;
        background: #ffb; border-color: black; 
        height: 394px; width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
        position: relative; z-index: 10;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It already wraps to the next line when there's not enough room for more elements?

Comment: @cimmanon based on your comment, I checked the pen cross browser. on chrome, the pen shows the body covered by a bg element... either html or body, not sure. in ffox, it shows all on one line in the container. In chromium it shows all in one line in a collapsed container. All this even tho 'prefixfree' has been added to the js (i know it's not perfect but i wouldn't expect such difference) I'm not sure what you're seeing.

Comment: Do you have a legitimate reason for making *everything* a flex container?

Comment: @cimmanon I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "legitimate" but the short answer to that is "yes". Unless I'm missing something about nesting flexes...